# What is the Kerberos method?

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to hive with jdbc. I keep getting this error. I tried looking it up but could not hind anything useful .

This is my connection string: 
`jdbc:hive2://hostname.xxx.com:10000/default;principal=hive/hostname.xxx.com@HADOOP_ENV.COM`

What is this error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil.hasKerberosTicket(Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That method exists in Hadoop 2.8 but not in Hadoop 2.7 -- so my guess is that your project dependencies are **not aligned with whatever version of Hadoop you have in Production**.

Code in `trunk`
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-auth/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/security/authentication/util/KerberosUtil.java

code in `branch-2.8.0`
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.8.0/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-auth/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/security/authentication/util/KerberosUtil.java

code in `branch-2.7.4`
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.7.4/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-auth/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/security/authentication/util/KerberosUtil.java

Answer (score 2):

Kerberos is an authentication protocol that is used by Hive server (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol))

The problem you are setting is more about a missing library in our pom.xml. Have you include `<artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>` ?

Comment: Thank you . Yes. I included all libraries. Is there any "check list" or is there any location where I can download all libraries. I included everything (in my opinion). I don't know if I'm missing anything

Comment: My 2 cents _(de la part de BNP Paribas CIB)_: when `NoSuchMethodError` pops up, check about a version mismatch in the libraries (compile-time vs. run-time).

Comment: Try to print the maven dependency tree (using mvn -X dependency:tree) and look for version conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I think your keberos ticket is not generated properly

Can you try running these two commands in order from the user you are trying to connect:

1. kdestroy (deleted any kerberos ticket generated before)
2. kinit (generates a new ticket)

Then try to connect again.

Comment: Come on... the message is not about an authentication error, it's about a version mismatch between the JAR seen at compile time and the JAR seen at run-time.